# Localization and caching - cache invalidation when culture is changed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, localization

Suppose I want to change the UI culture of my application. On the Index view I have some hyperlinks responsible for changing the language:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("SetCulture", "System", new { lang = "en", returnUrl = Request.RawUrl }, null)">
    <span>English</span>
</a>
<a ...
```

If I click on one of them, I'm redirected to the `SetCulture` action where, based on selected language, appropriate culture is created and persisted to the session (and to the cookie):

```
public class SystemController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SetCulture(string lang, string returnUrl)
    {
        SetCultureToCookie(lang);
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }        
}
```

Just before we will be redirected to our desirable action (e.g. `/Home/Index`):

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    ...
```

execution flow firstly goes through `OnActionExecuting` event. Here, culture previously stored to the session (and cookie) is extracted and assigned to the current thread:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{        
    protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);

        // btw: thread culture should be setup as soon as possible (OnActionExecuting is too
        // late, because error messages of attributes applied to models will not be translated)
        var culture = GetCultureFromCookie();
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
    }
}
```

After this is done, we have to finally find the appropriate view. Views hierarchy is straightforward here:

```
/Views
    /Home
        - Index.cshtml
        - Index_en.cshtml
        ...
```

Searching for the view is done by view engine, just before the view is rendered. I've written trivial custom engine, registered in `Application_Start`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new LocalizedRazorViewEngine());
    ...
```

Based on the current culture it looks for the appropriate view name:

```
public class LocalizedRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
    {
        useCache = false;   // <--- NOTICE THAT

        var culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;
        var isoLang = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;

        var locViewName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName) ? string.Format("{0}_{1}", viewName, culture) : viewName;
        var locMasterName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(masterName) ? string.Format("{0}_{1}", masterName, culture) : masterName;

        var result = base.FindView(controllerContext, locViewName, locMasterName, useCache);
        if (result.View == null)
        {
            locViewName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName) ? string.Format("{0}_{1}", viewName, isoLang) : viewName;
            locMasterName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(masterName) ? string.Format("{0}_{1}", masterName, isoLang) : masterName;

            result = base.FindView(controllerContext, locViewName, locMasterName, useCache);
            if (result.View == null)
                result = base.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, masterName, useCache);
        }

        return result;
    }
    ...
```

If I choose English language to be loaded (`/System/SetCulture?lang=en&returnUrl=%2FHome%2FIndex`), the method above returns `Index_en.cshtml` view.

Everything works fine but there is one drawback - there is **no caching** here (I assume no caching is enabled by default, as I'm using VS2012 and created skeleton of my application using default ASP.NET MVC 4 template). As you can see, at the beginning of `FindView` method, I've set `useCache` to `false` so the view engine doesn't try to look for any cached view - it will always perform full search. If I remove this poor line and **publish** this application to the hosting server, localization is not working - language changes has no effect, some older view is always rendered (i.e. if I select English language for the index view, no `Index_en.cshtml` is rendered but the previous one e.g. `Index.cshtml` or `Index_fr.cshtml`).

If you'd like to reproduce this issue in your development environment, you should compile the application in **release** mode and set `<compilation debug="false" />` in `web.config`, since MVC will not do any view lookup caching if you are running your application in debug mode.

I have some questions:

1. How to properly use the cache in my case? How to invalidate it when the
   language is changed?
2. How the caching on view engine level (`useCache`) differs from that
   one indicated by `[OutputCache]` attribute on controllers/actions? How to
   use that latter one here also in a correct manner?

BTW: As you can see, I'd like to avoid such a mechanism where current language is indicated by permanent prefix in url (like e.g. mypage.com/**en**/Index), because I don't like it.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seems to be more demanding because I didn't get any help, so I'll answer it myself. The `FindView` and the `FindPartialView` methods are internally called by the ASP.NET MVC framework with `useCache=true` first, then `useCache=false` if nothing is found. My view engine implementation was broken. For some reason, when the cache was enabled, engine served previously cached view. That's why I needed to disable caching, for the appropriate view to be always forcibly searched.

Now I've rewritten view engine logic. I'm not able to say exactly what was wrong in the previous one, but the current version is able to support localized views caching based on current UI culture correctly.

How the implementation looks like? Firstly, scan disk to verify if desired view file exists - if so, add it to cache (during further requests, such a file name is returned directly from our custom cache). Next, if such an appropriate localized view name is found, it is passed down to the ASP.NET MVC Framework to be further cached and served correctly for any subsequent requests:

```
public class LocalizedRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> _localizedViewsCache = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    private static readonly object _locker = new object();

    public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName,
                                              string masterName, bool useCache)
    {
        viewName = FindLocalization(controllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), viewName);
        return base.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, masterName, useCache);
    }

    public override ViewEngineResult FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialViewName,
                                                     bool useCache)
    {
        partialViewName = FindLocalization(controllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), partialViewName);
        return base.FindPartialView(controllerContext, partialViewName, useCache);
    }

    private string FindLocalization(string controllerName, string viewName)
    {
        var isoLangName = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
        var cacheKey = String.Format("{0}/{1}_{2}", controllerName, viewName, isoLangName);
        if (_localizedViewsCache.ContainsKey(cacheKey))
            return _localizedViewsCache[cacheKey];

        var cultureName = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;
        var localizedViews = new[]
            {
                string.Format("{0}_{1}", viewName, cultureName),
                string.Format("{0}_{1}", viewName, isoLangName)
            };

        string foundViewName = null;
        foreach (var view in localizedViews)
        {
            foreach (var location in ViewLocationFormats)
            {
                if (VirtualPathProvider.FileExists(String.Format(location, view, controllerName)))
                {
                    foundViewName = view;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (foundViewName != null)
                break;
        }

        viewName = foundViewName ?? viewName;
        lock (_locker)
        {
            if (_localizedViewsCache.ContainsKey(cacheKey))
                _localizedViewsCache[cacheKey] = viewName;
            else
                _localizedViewsCache.Add(cacheKey, viewName);
        }

        return viewName;
    }
}
```

What's more I decided to introduce also second type of caching to speedup my application and use Output Caching, to mark an action methods (or entire controllers) whose output will be cached. You have to keep in mind the language detection mechanism doesn't rely on URL schema in my approach. That's why I needed to implement some differential mechanism responsible for serving different view based on current UI culture, while the URL itself stays unchanged. I decided to use VaryBy tool provided by the framework, which is a way to instruct ASP.NET to keep parallel caches of the same page varied by some piece of data. It can be querystring or something completely different. In my case it is culture name stored in the cookie:

```
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server, Duration = 3600, VaryByCustom = "culture")]
public class HomeController : BaseController
```

In `Global.asax`:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
    if ("culture".Equals(custom))
    {
        var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("myapp.culture.name");
        var culture = cookie != null
                          ? CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cookie.Value).Name
                          : Guid.NewGuid().ToString();  // if culture cookie doesn't exist, do not rely 
                                                        // on cache - generate random guid to bypass it
        return culture;
    }
    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
}
```

For each unique parameter (here, culture value stored in the cookie) ASP.NET will keep a cached copy of such a page requested previously under that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap **ViewLocationCache**. For example:

```
public class LocalizedRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public LocalizedRazorViewEngine()
    {
        ViewLocationCache = new LocalizedViewLocationCache(ViewLocationCache);
    }
}

public class LocalizedViewLocationCache : IViewLocationCache
{
    public LocalizedViewLocationCache(IViewLocationCache innerCache)
    {
        _innerCache = innerCache ?? DefaultViewLocationCache.Null;
    }

    public string GetViewLocation(HttpContextBase httpContext, string key)
    {
        return _innerCache.GetViewLocation(httpContext, generateCacheKey(key));
    }

    public void InsertViewLocation(HttpContextBase httpContext, string key, string virtualPath)
    {
        _innerCache.InsertViewLocation(httpContext, generateCacheKey(key), virtualPath);
    }

    private string generateCacheKey(string key)
    {
        return string.Format(":LocalizedViewCacheEntry:{0}:{1}",
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName, key);
    }

    private readonly IViewLocationCache _innerCache;
}
```